# How to track changes in a config file (i.e. XML file) in real time

Tags: display

I would like to know how to **monitor changes in real time** in a file in **Windows**. I've found other answers like using *tail* but this only works for log files or similar, where changes are made at the end of the file.

In my situation, I need to monitor changes in an **XML file** in real time. Actually I'm monitoring this file manually by:

- Copy config.xml to config.backup
- Make changes in the main program through the GUI (one at a time)
- Compare config.backup with config.xml using WinMerge
- Repeat the process

I would like to have something like RegFromApp that watches changes in the registry made by a process. I've tried ProcMon by it indicates that the file is changed but not the change made to it.

Any idea would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible (yes, I said that word) to do this if the file is opened for exclusive access by the program doing the updating. If it's open for shared access, all you can do is wait for the filesystem event that it was changed, and then re-read the entire contents of the file... but by the time you do, it might've been changed again, and there's no guarantee that you can trap each individual write on the monitoring side.